# limit number of repetitions

Tags: python, regex

I need to determine how to much a src string by a pat string like:

```
src ='AAAABBBB'
pat ='(A+|B+)B+'
```

However, '+' matches any 1 or any number of appearance, it might be extremely slow when src is huge. But since I know exactly what the src is, I could design a pat to match exactly how many 'A' or 'B' appear in each period, like,

```
pat = '(A|B)\4B\4'
```

But my question also requires a syntax that takes 4 appearance or less, like

```
pat= '(A|B)\4(or less)B\4(or less)'
```

Anyone knows this syntax?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can specify a specific number of repetitions with the `{m}` syntax, where *m* is the number of repetitions expected:

```
A{4}B{4}
```

would require *exactly* four `A` and four `B` characters.

There is similar syntax to specify a range instead of a fixed number; from the [Regular Expression syntax documentation](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `{m}`
> Specifies that exactly *m* copies of the previous RE should be matched; fewer matches cause the entire RE not to match. For example, `a{6}` will match exactly six `'a'` characters, but not five.
>
> `{m,n}`
> Causes the resulting RE to match from *m* to *n* repetitions of the preceding RE, attempting to match as many repetitions as possible. For example, `a{3,5}` will match from 3 to 5 `'a'` characters. Omitting *m* specifies a lower bound of zero, and omitting *n* specifies an infinite upper bound. As an example, `a{4,}b` will match `aaaab` or a thousand `'a'` characters followed by a `b`, but not `aaab`. The comma may not be omitted or the modifier would be confused with the previously described form.
>
> `{m,n}?`
> Causes the resulting RE to match from *m* to *n* repetitions of the preceding RE, attempting to match as few repetitions as possible. This is the non-greedy version of the previous qualifier. For example, on the 6-character string `'aaaaaa'`, `a{3,5}` will match 5 `'a'` characters, while `a{3,5}?` will only match 3 characters.

Comment: Good! But what if I cannot determine if it is greedy or non-greedy?

Comment: @Jun: What do you mean? Variable-size quantifiers (`*`, `+`, `{m,n}`) all come in greedy and non-greedy variants; the latter by adding `?` to the quantifier. `{m}` can never be greedy or non-greedy, it matches an exact number of characters instead.

Comment: OK I understand, so greedy or non-greedy happens only if matching has different results, if not matching at all, no greedy or non-greedy things to concern. Thanks

Comment: Not to forget: `{m,n}` and not `{m, n}` (the pattern should not have a space, otherwise it will interpret the curly braces as literals)

Comment: This might be a bit old, but if I want to choose exactly 2 or 4? 
Like `{2|4}` but works.

Comment: @sheldonzy: then use a group of two patterns separated by `|`, e.g. `(?:f{4}|f{2})`. Put the long version first if later patterns could also match the extra characters; it'll be considered before testing if the shorter version matches (`|` alternatives are always non-greedy).